# Dispute a declined flag

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

Is there some mechanism in Stackoverflow that allows me to refute a declined flag? This question was put on hold as too broad [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26938754/how-to-build-map-based-web-app-in-mean-stack)

However, I had originally flagged it as VLQ, so I feel that it should have been marked as a helpful flag in that case, even if the specific reason for it being flagged was different.

I'd like to mention this to the moderator, but there seems to be no way to do this.

Comment: VLQ is asking for deletion. Why not just flag for closure?

Comment: As a side note, don't worry too much about the occasional declined or disputed flag. Unless your ratio is insanely unbalanced in the "declined" direction, a few here and there won't affect anything. To answer your question directly, there is no direct mechanism to refute declined flags on SO.

Comment: Thanks @PaulRichter that answers my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, the VLQ flag keeps popping up as a flag that people misuse. Here's the very simple rule that I use:

Is it the post **utter gibberish**? Things like "asdfasdfasfdasdf", or "The of my limbo emu California." If yes, then the VLQ flag applies (true for questions and answers). If not, then maybe the post just needs to be edited, or it may need to be closed.(for questions). Or it might need another kind of flag, if the situation demands it. But if it is not gibberish, VLQ does not apply.

And no, there is no formal way to respond to a declined flag. There's a good reason for this: **can you imagine the load this would create if mods had to answer to such replies?** The occasional pain of having a flag declined, correctly or not, is well worth preventing the load that such replies would cause. Note that we don't have to assume ill-will on the part of the flaggers. The natural human impulse when being told "you did wrong" is to reply to at least explain oneself, but even if everybody accepted the verdict of the moderators and replied with "oh, sorry", it would be disruptive to the work of the mods.

Comment: `"The of my limbo emu California."` ... hey, who told you my password.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that @Louis. I will use your rule when deciding to use the VLQ flag.

Answer (score 7):

That post was two minutes old when you flagged it for a moderator to delete it. It did not require moderator attention at that point, so the flag was rightly declined.